# Email open/click tracking in Gmail using hidden image

Tags: gmail, tracking, user-agent

I'm using email tracking mechanism in email by adding a hidden image URL `https://example.com/tracking/open/SOME_UNIQUE_ID`
The image URL converted to the following on Gmail.

```
<img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/LP0uwO5fHA2LPxEfKkef1e9imTurKBU5wawN6p8SArM9l6CRtsT_dmRtTqfZDVpmWRlhgnRqr0uA9QO7w85wlGOl5DUl2G4rZ-0JQI4pXmlzjGho6yWUCA03oRRfwDOvd5HeGokeHMpHFQ=s0-d-e1-ft#https://example.com/tracking/open/SOME_UNIQUE_ID" width="0" height="0" border="0" alt="" role="presentation" class="CToWUd">
```

The problem here I can't detect the real user agent or IP, because it's always back related to google Ips and user agent `'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)`

I see some people get the correct Ip and location for GMAIL open/click tracking.

I checked all request headers but nothing useful for the real user. it's all related to google.

any suggestions for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me taking user agent value from the header helped. If user agent is equals to "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246 Mozilla/5.0" then its a Google bot.

```
private static boolean IsGoogleBot(HttpRequest req){
    var userAgent = req.Headers["User-Agent"];
    return userAgent == "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246 Mozilla/5.0";}
```

The ip address will point to Google (on Gmail im sure), but with this method you can detect a real email opening.

Comment: This seems brittle, as Google can change this any time.

Comment: It does seem brittle. @Robert - But just came across this issue and Google is using the exact same user agent as of today. It can change in the future, but not now. 

Also, they can use this with other gmail apps
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)